# Modal transition effect

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Well I'm with the following doubt, I have a modal [ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/) when I'm running on iphones the input transition comes from low up to cover the tola screen so it's down to top.

With this library, can I change this transition? I need the transition to appear from the middle of the screen, this should happen the same way for android, iphone and windows phones

I'm trying to do this:

```
openModal() {
 let options: NativeTransitionOptions = {
  direction: 'down',
  duration: 500,
  slowdownfactor: 3,
  slidePixels: 20,
  iosdelay: 100,
  androiddelay: 150,
  fixedPixelsTop: 0,
  fixedPixelsBottom: 60
};

this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options);
  let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(SlideAccessibility, null);
  myModal.present();
}
```

I realized by the documentation that I have how to pass options for the call, maybe in her I can do the effect that I need, however as the documentation is poor I did not find anything on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by checking the code until I found the possible transitions. So I discovered what can be passed in `options` the final code looks like this:

```
OpenModal () {
 Let options: ModalOptions = {
  ShowBackdrop: false,
  EnterAnimation: 'modal-md-slide-in',
  LeaveAnimation: 'modal-md-slide-out',
};

This.nativePageTransitions.slide (options);
  Let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create (SlideAccessibility, null, options);
  MyModal.present ();
}
```

To stay in tip the class is this and these are the options that can be passed as parameter:

```
Export interface ModalOptions {
  ShowBackdrop ?: boolean;
  EnableBackdropDismiss ?: boolean;
  EnterAnimation ?: string;
  LeaveAnimation ?: string;
  CssClass ?: string;
}
```

And these are the 4 types of possible transitions already preconfigured:

```
Modal-slide-in [Refers to the ios effect, down-up]
Modal-slide-out [Refers to ios effect, exit up]
Modal-md-slide-in [Refers to the effect of android, half-up]
Modal-md-slide-out [Refers to the android effect, top to middle]
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! It will definitely help some other SO users. +1